# Why is $\bigcap_{\lambda\ge0}I^\lambda_0 = \bigcap_{\lambda\lt0}I^\lambda_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In "Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis" by Smith the excercise 1.2 (k) reads:

" ... write down the set which is different ... In parts (j) and (k), the symbol $I^s_r$ denotes the set of real numbers $\{\eta\ |\ r\le\eta\lt s\}$ where $r$ and $s$ are themselves real numbers.

(k) (i)$\bigcap_{\lambda\gt0}I^\lambda_0$,  (ii)$\bigcap_{\lambda\ge0}I^\lambda_0$, 
 (iii)$\bigcap_{\lambda\lt0}I^\lambda_0$
"

My thinking is that (i)=(ii) which is a set of 0 to $\lambda$, but not included. The (iii) will always have {} because $\lambda\lt0$ will never satisfy $I^\lambda_0$; $\{\eta\ |\ 0\le\eta\lt \lambda\}$.

The answer on the other hand says that (i) differs from the other two; which implies (ii)=(iii). Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) is not empty, since $0$ satisfies the inequality $\ 0 \le 0\lt \lambda$ for any strictly positive $\lambda$, and so $0$ will be in the intersection.

(ii) and (iii) are both empty.

(ii) is empty because the case $\lambda = 0$ leaves a set empty, and so the intersection of all of them will be too.

(iii) is empty for the reason you stated.